# Convert JSON object to associative php array

Tags: php, json

I am using AngularJS with PHP on server side to access database. To make a POST method I write this request:

```
var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'action.php',
      data:{'tblname': 'user',
      'conditions' : {
            'select' : 'user_name',
            'where' : {
                 'user_category' : 'admin'
             },
       'order_by' : 'user_name'
       }   
};
```

In PHP I want to convert my JSON `data` object into a php associative array.

```
$request_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$conditions = json_decode($request_data->conditions,true);
```

I used `json_decode` but it seems its not converting the JSON object to associative php array. I want the JSON object to be converted to the following PHP array:

```
$conditions = array(
        "select" => "user_name",
        "where" =>
            array("user_category" => "admin") ,
        "order_by" => "user_name"
);
```

Comment: Assuming that `$request_data` contains what you expect it to; you have already decoded the data, so it is no longer a string but an object. You should either decode the whole thing as an array or cast the `conditions` section / object to an array.

Comment: `$conditions = (array) $request_data->conditions;`

Comment: I replaced `$conditions = json_decode($request_data->conditions,true);` with `$conditions = (array) $request_data->conditions;` and now it works. Thanks @jeroen and @splash58

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `json_decode` data that has already been decoded.

Once you do:

```
$request_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
```

You've already have the information in an associative array. (The second parameter tells `json_decode()` [that you want your result as an associative array and not as an object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)).

The next step is as simple as:

```
$conditions = $request_data['conditions'];
```